# converting table with many columns to many tables with two columns

Tags: sql, database-design, data-structures, graph, tree

Is it possible to convert table with many columns to many tables of two columns without losing data?
I will show what I mean:

Let say I have a table

```
+------------+----------+-------------+
|country code|   site   | advertiser  |
+------------+----------+-------------|
|      US    | facebook | Cola        |
|      US    | yahoo    | Pepsi       |
|      FR    | facebook | BMW         |
|      FR    | yahoo    | BMW         |
+------------+----------+-------------+
```

The number of rows = [(number of countries) X (number of sites)] and the advertiser column is a variable that gets a value from a list with a limited number of advertisers

Is it possible to transform the 3 columns table to several tables with 2 columns without losing data?

If create two tables likes this I will surly lose data:

```
+------------+------------+
|country code| advertiser |
+------------+------------+
|  US        | Cola,Pepsi |
|-------------------------|
|  FR        | BMW        |
+-------------------------+

+------------+------------+
|   site     | advertiser |
+------------+------------+
|  facebook  | Cola,BMW   |
|-------------------------|
|  yahoo     | Pepsi,BMW  |
+-------------------------+
```

But is I add a third "connection" table this will it help keep all the data and have the ability to recreate the original table?

```
+--------------+--------------------+
| country code |  site              |
+--------------+--------------------+
|    US        | facebook,yahoo     |
|-----------------------------------|
|    FR        | facebook,yahoo     |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't really make sense.  It looks like you have a three-entity relationship in your first table, so it would be the proper way to represent that.

Comment: But in theory can you transfer the thee-entity relationship to several two entity relationship?

Comment: Really? I'm not familiar with that theory.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, just asking if it is? and if you can reference me to the information

Comment: Ok. But if you split to four or five? Is there an algorithm to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the table you specify can be 'converted' into into multiple tables is determined  by whether the table is in fifth normal form i.e. if and only if every non-trivial join dependency in it is implied by the candidate keys.

If the table is in fifth normal form then it cannot be converted into multiple tables. If the table is not in fifth normal form then it is in one of the four lower normal forms and can be further normalized into fifth normal form by 'converting' it into multiple tables.

A table's normal form is determined by the column dependencies. These are determined by the meaning of the table i.e. what this table represents in the real world. You have not stated what the meaning of this table is and so whether this particular table can be converted into multiple tables is unknown.

You need to understand the process of **normalization** and using this you should be able to determine if it is *possible to convert table with many columns to many tables of two columns without losing data?* based on the column dependencies in the table.

Comment: I understand now that it is impossible to do that in general case. This is a good source of information http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm#label4.2

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).  Certainly it is much better than your proposal for keeping field values organized and not requiring a search of the field to determine if a value is present.